# Shell script. what does it mean?

Tags: shell, cron

Do you know what does the shell script below??

```
00 5 * * * file.sh --date="2020-08-03"
```

Comment: Did you do *any* research before asking this question?  If yes, please include your research detail in future questions.  If not, please read how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 2):

The script isn't shell script but probably CRON job script.

It runs a command `/client/user/download_files.sh --date="2020-08-03"` every day at 5:00 AM.